# SHAREPOINT\system account not visible in Group membership in browser but showing up in powershell

Tags: 2013, groups

I have a SharePoint group with two members.
1. SHAREPOINT\system
2. Domain\user

If I go to

> Settings -> User Group

and view the members of this group, it only shows Domain\user.

If I get the group in Powershell and check the users, it shows SHAREPOINT\system and Domain\user.

Used the following command to check in Powershell.

```
$w = Get-SPWeb http://site
$g = $w.SiteGroups["GroupName"]
$g.Users
```

What is the reason for this difference between the results from UI and Powershell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is just because "SHAREPOINT\system" is actually a "logical" account that has no real "physical" correspondence, while "domain\user" is something that maps to an actual user, in this case a AD domain one. For these reason, I would assume SharePoint filters out the SharePoint\System user from the group members section in the web UI while it retains it when using PowerShell - which usually is used by more "advanced" users.

As a side note, "SharePoint\System" is just a name that SharePoint uses when an account is given system-level permission. Most of the time, this means that you are either using the Farm account or the account the current app pool is running as (this can actually be modified in the Central Admin - there should be an "Act as system" privilege, active by default, that you can toggle in the User Policies section for a web-application).

Anyway, what you are experiencing it completely normal AFAIK, so you probably shouldn't give it much importance.